# Making wordpress headers conditional to the incoming URL

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WP site that has 5 different domain names associated with it.  The client would like (if possible) to have a different header for the site depending on the domain name.

For example, Jenson Tire (www.jensontire.com) would have a different logo and social media links than Canopy Tires (www.canopytires.com) and depending on how the user arrives at the site, it would show that header file.  The content throughout the rest of the site would be 100% identical - the only difference would be the headers.

Is this possible? Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!  I learn new stuff from you guys on here every day!

Answer (score 0):

Typically the vhost configuration is handled at the http server layer (apache most likely, look up "apache virtual hosts"). That said, it's possible to check the hostname being requested with the super global: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ..

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
  case 'host_1.com':
    $img_url = '/some.jpg';
  break;
  case 'host_2.com':
    $img_url = '/another.jpg';
  break;
  default:
    $img_url = '/default.jpg';
  break;
}
```

Cheers